# Make a point process from another?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

> Blue boats are passing on a river and their arrival times are modeled by a renewal point process. Place red boats on the river according to a point process $P$ such that the arrival times of all of the boats (the superposition process) becomes another renewal process. Find $P$.

In other words, find a point process whose superposition with a given renewal process is another renewal process. Note the **causality constraint**: when you place red boats, you don't have any information about the arrival times of the blue boats in the future.

**What I found was not enough:**

1. A solution for a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1544875/increasing-the-rate-of-a-renewal-process), without causality
2. [Poisson and alternating renewal processes with superposition a renewal process](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/mana.19730570125/full)
3. [Renewal Processes Decomposable into i.i.d. Components](http://www.jstor.org.silk.library.umass.edu/stable/pdf/1426802.pdf?refreqid=search:5c495542d3440ef22ed4a258e7b223c1)
4. [Superposition and Decomposition of Stationary Point Processes](http://www.jstor.org.silk.library.umass.edu/stable/pdf/3213111.pdf?refreqid=search%3A5c495542d3440ef22ed4a258e7b223c1)
5. [Almost Sure Comparisons of Renewal Processes and Poisson Processes](http://www.jstor.org.silk.library.umass.edu/stable/pdf/3689225.pdf?refreqid=search%3A5c495542d3440ef22ed4a258e7b223c1)
6. [Superposition of Renewal Processes](http://www.jstor.org.silk.library.umass.edu/stable/pdf/1427512.pdf?refreqid=search%3Ad7219a5e5ebbab0b9072f3d94051da0c)
7. [On the Superposition of Point Processes](http://www.jstor.org.silk.library.umass.edu/stable/pdf/2984262.pdf?refreqid=search%3Ad7219a5e5ebbab0b9072f3d94051da0c)
8. [Pairs of renewal processes whose superposition is a renewal process](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304414999000952)
9. [ON QUEUEING SYSTEMS VITH RENEWAL DEPARTURE PROCESSES](http://www.jstor.org.silk.library.umass.edu/stable/pdf/1426624.pdf?refreqid=search%3A5c495542d3440ef22ed4a258e7b223c1)

Comment: To me your casuality constraint is not very clear. We know that blue boats arrive according to a renewal process. Usually, by observing blue boats for some time, we can learn the distribution of inter-arrival times. Once we know the distribution we can calculate the distributuion of the residual time (also called forward recurrence time) until the next arrival of a blue boat. So the future becomes known (probabilistically).